# Conditionally formatting elements in a list

Tags: output-formatting

I have a list `{{a1, a2, a3},{b1, b2, b3}, ...}` and I want to replace the numbers less than 10 by `0x` (just insert a 0 before the element, so that `2 -> 02`, `3 -> 03`, etc). How can I do that?

To clarify, I will later export this table and run it through a program that will upload it to a database. These number are identifications for different objects, and for some reason the list needs to be all aligned. If I just export it as it is, I would get something like

> ```
> 1  2  3
> 20  40  55
> ```

which the program can't read.

Comment: so you want  to convert numbers to strings ...

Comment: What are the elements of your list?  What is your motivation for wanting to do this?  `02` is precisely the same number as `2`.  Are you working with numbers or strings?  It sounds like you want `IntegerString[..., 10, 2]`.

Comment: Presumably, it is to align elements in a Table or Grid, e.g.,
list = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {10, 3}];
IntegerString[list, 10, 2] // Grid

Comment: Yes, sorry if it wasn't clear, but I need to export the file and it would be easier to have it all aligned in mathematica than to add the zeroes later myself.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a job for [`IntegerString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntegerString.html):

```
m = RandomInteger[15, {2, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{4, 8, 3, 14, 0}, {12, 7, 11, 1, 7}}
> ```

```
IntegerString[m, 10, 2]
```

> ```
> {{"04", "08", "03", "14", "00"}, {"12", "07", "11", "01", "07"}}
> ```

By default string characters are not printed in tables and grids so it looks like this:

```
% // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you  need `NumberForm` with padding with `0` on the left:

```
lst = RandomInteger[20, {10, 5}];
newlst = Map[If[# >= 10, #,
             NumberForm[#, 1, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}]] &, lst, {-1}];

Row[Panel /@ (Style[#, 20] & /@ TableForm /@ {lst, newlst}), Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Note:

> NumberForm acts as a "wrapper", which affects printing, but not evaluation.

Comment: thanks. It doesn't however address negative number, and they stay as -2 insted of -02

Answer (score 1):

This may be easier.

```
lst = RandomInteger[20, {10, 5}]; 
lst /. x_?(# < 10 &) -> NumberForm[x, 1, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have a similar problem but with dates. I need to change the format of an entry if it is a string representing a date (18/12/2013 19:53 for example) and leave it alone if it is not. I think I need to Map my date function to the list, but conditionally so that it doesn't map on to strings that are not dates. How can I do this?

Comment: is this good for you: {"18/12/2013 19:53", "r", 5} /. 
 _String?(StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ "/" ~~ ___] &) :> ee

Comment: I will try that but can you please explain what you have written in words so I know what it means? I think it means "take this list {"18/12/2013 19:53", "r", 5} and replace all strings with the format matching x/x with a format of xx-" The part after /. I'm a bit hazy on what it means or what I'm doing. I'd like to understand properly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just tried it but I don't know what to put instead of the ee-. I'm trying to replace my date of this format 18/12/2013 18:53 with a date of this format 2013-12-18 hh24:mm:ss (where the ss will just be 00).

Comment: Is all of your data dates Strings?

Comment: My data is a row, column setup, so a list of lists. The one column that I want to apply this to is a mixture of date strings, normal strings and reals and some other data types so I can't simply use the Head of string to replace. Eg of my data: {{"aaa","18/12/2013 23:32",433},{"aaa","test",345},{"ddd",455,675}}, the second "column" being the one I need to do the replacement on if it's a date of the form I'm looking to replace.

Comment: can you clarify your results. how comes 18/12/2013 18:53 become 2013-12-18 hh24:mm:ss? should it be 2013-12-18 hh18:53mm:00ss or 2013-12-18 18:53:00?

Comment: the result of 18/12/2013 18:53 should be 2013-12-18 18:53:00

Comment: StringReplace["18/12/2013 19:53", 
 a__ ~~ "/" ~~ b__ ~~ "/" ~~ c__ ~~ " " ~~ d__ ~~ ":" ~~ e__ ~~ 
   f___ :> c ~~ "-" ~~ b ~~ "-" ~~ a ~~ " " ~~ d ~~ ":" ~~ e ~~ ":00"]

Comment: this will be ok if you don't have :00 (:ss) in all strings

Comment: Worked! Thanks SO much.

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want strings as the output, this is an approach that is completely customizable because it applies a converter function (`convert`) that is defined by your specifications. I start with some test data in `m`, and put the converted data in the list `new`:

```
m = {{4,8,-3,14,0},{12,7,11,1,-7}}
convert[number_] := 
 If[Abs[number] < 10, StringInsert[ToString[number], "0", -2],
  ToString[number], number]

new = Map[convert, m, {-1}]

(*
==> {{"04", "08", "-03", "14", "00"}, 
     {"12", "07", "11", "01", "-07"}}
*)
```

The result is a list in which all numbers have been converted to strings. In the `Map` function that creates the result, the level specification `{-1}` means that the `convert` function is applied to the individual elements of the list `m`.

The `If` statement in `convert` inserts a string `"0"` only if the number is single-digit. If `convert` is applied to something that's not a number, it returns the unchanged argument.